# Extracting Channel Data from fetch_feed()

Tags: rss

How do I access the channel data when using fetch_feed()? I want to use the channel title.

TIA

Further info:

A typical RSS feed (taken from wikipedia)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
 <title>RSS Title</title>
 <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
 <link>http://www.example.com/main.html</link>
 <copyright>2020 Example.com All rights reserved</copyright>
 <lastBuildDate>Mon, 6 September 2010 00:01:00 +0000</lastBuildDate>
 <pubDate>Sun, 6 September 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
 <ttl>1800</ttl>

 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
  <link>http://www.example.com/blog/post/1</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">7bd204c6-1655-4c27-aeee-53f933c5395f</guid>
  <pubDate>Sun, 6 September 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
 </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

I wish to extract and use the channel title instead of the item title (because the mastodon feed doesn't use them currently).

I can access the data in <item> but accessing parts of <channel> I can't work out.

Does that help?

Comment: can you describe what you meant by channel? Is this a standard RSS feed of posts/entries or something else? I'm not seeing code in your question that can be modified either

Comment: Added information above.

Comment: According to the documentation `fetch_feed()` returns a SimplePie object, and a very quick search for "SimplePie channel" returns https://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/get_channel_tags. Have you tried that?

Comment: ooooh you're trying to display mastodon toots and want to grab the profile name from the main title

Comment: I expect that by the time I work out the vagaries of developing a wordpress plugin, Mastodon will have fixed their feed mechanics.  But it's a good learning process. I just wish the documentation was more helpful.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official WP docs say it returns a `SimplePie` object and the very first example in the SimplePie documentation is:

```php
// Single feed
$feed = new SimplePie('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache');
echo $feed->get_title();
```

https://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/start

`$feed` is the same type of object as the return value of `fetch_feed`:

> #### Return
>
> `SimplePie`|`WP_Error` `SimplePie` object on success or `WP_Error` object on failure.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/

Just make sure to call `is_wp_error` to check for failures

Comment: Thank you very much.